# Image corrupt when trying to convert B64 string to Image using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to convert a stream to image using C#, but the image is appearing corrupt.

Here is how i'm getting the BaseString representation

```
byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\jay.raj\Desktop\images\images\tiger.jpg");

string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
```

Now I'm passing this to a function which converts it into Stream and tries to convert it into image file.

```
 byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mySettingInfo.FileToUpload);
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
 UtilityHelper.UploadImageFormDevice(stream, ref ss);
```

Here is the `UploadImageFormDevice` function:

```
public static ResponseBase UploadImageFormDevice(Stream image, ref string imageName)
    {
        ResponseBase rep = new ResponseBase();
        try
        {
            string filname = imageName;
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\jay.raj\Desktop\Upload\";

            if (filname == string.Empty)
                filname = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";
            filePath = filePath + "\\" + filname;
            FileStream fileStream = null;
            using (fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                const int bufferLen = 1024;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
                int count = 0;
                while ((count = image.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
                {
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                fileStream.Close();

                image.Close();
            }
            imageName = filname;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rep.Code = 1000;
            rep.Message = "Server Error";

        }
        return rep;
    }
```

Comment: I don't have enough time to investigate, but this part is wrong: `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` - you shouldn't deal with any encoding, when working with image data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @naivists wrote try replace this line:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mySettingInfo.FileToUpload);
```

To this line:

```
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(mySettingInfo.FileToUpload);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to transfer a file from `@"C:\Users\jay.raj\Desktop\images\images\tiger.jpg"` to `@"C:\Users\jay.raj\Desktop\Upload\" + "\\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg"`.

In your case you read the file as a byte array, convert it into a base 64 coded string and then again into a byte array. This is unnecessary and error prone. In your case you missed the decoding.

If you ignore for a moment that it is an image and see it just as a bunch of bytes things might get easier.

```
string srcPath = @"C:\Users\jay.raj\Desktop\images\images\tiger.jpg";
string dstPath = @"C:\Users\jay.raj\Desktop\Upload\" + "\\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";

byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(srcPath);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(dstPath, imageArray);
```

Comment: Please note that those double backslashes after "Upload" are not normal!